# How does SwiftUI's List update the selection binding?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm really struggling to understand how the `List(selection:)` causes an update to the selection binding.

I am unpicking the Apple sample code at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/building_a_great_mac_app_with_swiftui

The project is `Session2/Part2-End/GardenApp.xcodeproj`

There is a sidebar on the left, and the main detail view on the right. The `ContentView` looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    @SceneStorage("selection") private var selectedGardenID: Garden.ID?
    @AppStorage("defaultGarden") private var defaultGardenID: Garden.ID?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Sidebar(selection: selection)
            GardenDetail(garden: selectedGarden)
        }
    }

    private var selection: Binding<Garden.ID?> {
        Binding(get: { selectedGardenID ?? defaultGardenID }, set: { selectedGardenID = $0 })
    }

    private var selectedGarden: Binding<Garden> {
        $store[selection.wrappedValue]
    }
}
```

and the Sidebar like this:

```
struct Sidebar: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    @SceneStorage("expansionState") var expansionState = ExpansionState()
    @Binding var selection: Garden.ID?

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $expansionState[store.currentYear]) {
                ForEach(store.gardens(in: store.currentYear)) { garden in
                    SidebarLabel(garden: garden)
                        .badge(garden.numberOfPlantsNeedingWater)
                }
            } label: {
                Label("Current", systemImage: "chart.bar.doc.horizontal")
            }

            Section("History") {
                GardenHistoryOutline(range: store.previousYears, expansionState: $expansionState)
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 250)
    }
}
```

Now the `SidebarLabel` view does not have any reference to the selection binding; yet, when you click on one of the labels, the selection updates and the binding propagates up to the `ContentView` and therefore the `GardenDetai` view is updated with the new selection.

My question is: how does clicking on one of the sidebar items cause the selection binding to be updated since there is no reference to the selection binding? Does the `ForEach` have anything to do with it?

If so, how can I add 'ad hoc' items that do not participate in a `ForEach` like this? If not, what is going on?

Comment: try to set id with selection ```List(d: \.self, selection: $selection))

Comment: @RajaKishan could you please elaborate? How is it updating the selection binding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List` and `ForEach` work together here. The list sees that it has a ForEach over Garden in it, and the ForEach automatically provides a `.tag(garden.id)`

In a pure `List` form is would look like this, and probably shows much clearer what happens. I included an explicit `.tag()` but this will be generated automatically.

```
struct Sidebar2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    @Binding var selection: Garden.ID?

    var body: some View {
        List(store.gardens(in: store.currentYear), selection: $selection) { garden in
                    SidebarLabel(garden: garden)
                        .tag(garden.id) // << not needed, will be done implicitly
                        .badge(garden.numberOfPlantsNeedingWater)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 250)
    }
}
```

Because of the sections the `List`is used as a wrapper around `ForEach`. But the principle is still the same. The `ForEach` hands its automatically generated `id` up to the `List` and sets the `selection`.

If you want to add custom elements to the Sidebar you can give them an explicit `.tag` ... you just have to find out where to decode these custom tags and what to display accordingly in the detail view.

Comment: That's awesome, it works. Thanks! One question though: how did you know this? The Apple documentation is absolutely shocking. I have no idea where I'm supposed to get this sort of information. There are zero usages examples in their documentation.

Comment: good question :) https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui is a great basic course. And for advanced topics: https://swiftui-lab.com. He also has an App that works very well as a documentation source ... its a small investment but worth it. And of course ... practice

Comment: Yeah, I have nearly finished 100 Days of Hacking with SwiftUI! I have all of his books too but am really looking for reference material. I shall try the lab you suggested. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

You can find more details in the [documentation for List](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list), check out the example under "Supporting Multi-Dimensional Lists".

But basically, this is what is happening:

1. The line `List(selection: $selection)` stores the selected garden in the `selection` variable of the `SideBar`.
2. The `selection` variable of `SideBar` is a **binding** from the `selection` variable in `ContentView` (see line `Sidebar(selection: selection)`), so when the former changes, the latter is updated  too.
3. The `selectedGarden` variable of `ContentView` is a computed property that returns the garden at the index of `selection.wrappedValue` - if `selection`'s value changes, the `selectedGarden` returns a different value.
4. The `GardenDetail` view shows the details according to the `selectedGarden` variable that is passed to it: `GardenDetail(garden: selectedGarden)`.

Changing the `selection` in `SideBar` changes also the `selection` in `ContenView`, which makes the `selectedGarden` return a different garden which updates the `GardenDetail` view.

Comment: Thank you, but I understand all that. What I am not understanding is how the sidebar is updating the selection binding which is passed to it. When you click on a sidebar item, somehow the selection binding is updated and the garden detail is displayed as you describe. How does the sidebar update the selection binding? There is no mention of this binding in the sidebar, other than in the 'List(selection: $selection)'. What is updatng it?

Comment: It is exactly that line `List(selection: $selection)` that is reading the selected item. Apple's documentation that I linked above explains: "To make members of a list selectable, provide a binding to a selection variable. Binding to a single instance of the list data’s `Identifiable.ID` type creates a single-selection list". Basically, you select an item and the `selection` variable stores the id.

Comment: Ok, I understand that too! There's one piece I don't understand and it seems I'm having difficulty expressing it clearly. When you click on an item in the sidebar, I would expect to see something along the lines of, "selection = clickedGarden". I see the selectkon binding in the list,m "List(selection: $selection)", but I don't see anywhere in the list where the binding's value is being changed. It is clearly happening automatically somehow, so when updating the binding, how does the framework know which new value to assign for the selection binding?

Comment: There is just a DisclosureGroup with a ForEach inside. It is not indicated which property of any of that stuff is the ID that should be assigned to the binding when the item is selected. I can only think that the ForEach is providing the ID; in which case, how to I add constant items to my List that do not participate in ForEach?

Comment: I think you are missing that `List` is a view struct itself. It keeps track of everything you pass in to it. There are a great deal of things that are going on under the hood that you can't see. I can't remember who, but one of the bloggers did a series of posts where they reimplemented different view structs in SwiftUI. Obviously, they weren't exactly like Apple's, but they gave a peek at  how some of these mechanisms work.